# React-bootstrap correct setup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

So I've been practicing react and now I find myself learning react-bootstrap. I cannot get it to work when my setup seem correct.

**I cloned a react boiler plate**

```
$ create-react-app myapp
```

**Then I installed bootsrap**

```
$ npm install --save react-bootstrap
```

**Then I added a `<Button>`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
         <Button>Default</Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Expected Outcome:**

[image]

**Actual Outcome:**

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to manually import Bootstrap CSS in your project with import.

Comment: @Shota did i not import it in my example? would help if you gave an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a the bootstrap style in your application.

From the [Bootstrap-react site](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html):

> Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css. However, some stylesheet is required to use these components.

They suggest using a cdn to load in the styles. You could include the following in the head of your index.html file:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Or you could grab another version from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7

Comment: Alternative if you want to serve the CSS yourself: add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` to your index.js.